# Adding infinite numbers for objects in a class (in theory)

Tags: c#

I am on my last project for my programming course, we are making a bus simulator where the passengers are gonna be made as objects.

I have managed to make the class and everything, but I am wondering if there is some way to make an infite number of objects instead. Instead of doing this down below i want it to make a new object everytime that option is picked. (We are making a menu for different methods, this one is for adding passengers)

```
 public void add_Passenger()
    {
        passenger passanger1 = new passenger();
        passanger1.name = Console.ReadLine();
        passanger1.age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        passanger1.destination = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        
    }
```

here is also the class itself if its needed

```
class passenger
{
    public string name;
    public int age;
    public int destination;
}
```

** edit **
ok not infinite, but i ment more that i want the program to make a new object whenever that option is picked instead of me having to make
passenger1
passenger2
passenger3

and so on. The bus is supposed to have a maximum of 25 passangers.
Sorry for my vague explanation im new to programming and my english is not super good

Comment: I'm guessing you want a `List<passenger>`, but that has limits. Anything will though since you don't have infinite memory...

Comment: Well, you can't create an *infinite* number of objects because that would consume an *infinite* amount of memory and processing resources, which your computer doesn't have.  Given that, it's not really clear to me what you mean.  Can you provide a more complete example and indicate what specifically isn't working as expected?  Currently you have an `add_Passenger` method which doesn't really do anything.  It creates an instance of an object, sets a couple of properties, and then ends without ever doing anything with that object.  Did you mean to do something with that object?

Comment: Clearly they don't want *literally* infinite amount, they're trying to say that they don't want to make separate variables (`passenger1`, `passenger2`, etc) for each passenger.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/tutorials/arrays-and-collections

Comment: yes what guy incognito said guys is what i ment, sorry for my bad english

david that method is supposed to add new passengers to the bus, i am also gonna make methods that shows the passenger, sorts the passengers and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, it sounds like you want to store your `passenger` objects in a higher scope that persists outside of that method.  Your first stop on that journey is a class-level member.

First let's fix your class to use C# conventions (capital letter, properties instead of fields):

```
class Passenger
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public int Destination { get; set; }
}
```

Now in the class with the method, add a field to hold your "passengers".  For example:

```
class YourClass
{
    private IList<Passenger> passengers = new List<Passenger>();

    public void AddPassenger()
    {
        var passenger = new Passenger();
        passenger.Name = Console.ReadLine();
        passenger.Age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        passenger.Destination = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        passengers.Add(passenger);
    }

    // the rest of the class...
}
```

You'll notice I updated some names there as well, just to stick with convention.  There are several more improvements which can be made, such as error handling for input, using specific prompts for input, separating the reading of input from the logic that uses the input, etc., etc.  But we're starting small for academic purposes.

Now your class instance is keeping a list of "passengers" at the class level, and each time that method is called it will add another "passenger" to that ongoing list.

You can update the private field to be a public property if other code needs to access this list.  Or you can continue to lift the scope of where it's stored into something that persists outside of the class, such as a database or file somewhere.  Where you go from here really depends on the needs of the system being built.  But *overall* if you just want to keep that object after the method ends, you just need to save it to something outside the scope of the method.